How do you know when wind is tailwind or headwind based off of a figure or like looking at the weather?



So when I drawed the runways and then where the wind is comes from. And I still don’t know how to know if it’s tailwind or headwind. When I visualize it in my head the wind is coming right and is pushing the side of the airplane at all directions. How should I visualize it and what helps you understand if it’s head or tail wind?

Thank you

To reiterate what I mentioned in my answer: Your yellow line depicting the landing airplane is backwards. The yellow arrow shows the airplane landing to the East, so it would be using Runway 9. The question asks about an airplane landing to the West, so it would be using Runway 27.

Yea I have it landing, wait I thought runways are opposite so that is why I put the 27 on the left side. I'm confused.

Runways aren't "opposite." Runways are numbered according to what your compass indicates when you're pointed down the runway. Read my answer carefully.

The problem is you have the compass orientation backwards.  North is top, as the little black pointer shows, so runway 36 is landing toward the top of the image not the bottom, and runway 27 is landing toward the left of the image, not the right.
Once that is resolved, you are landing on 27 as per the question, so right to left, or to the west, and the sock shows the wind from the northwest, so right quartering headwind.

A tail wind is a wind blowing from the tail to the nose, a head wind is a wind blowing from the nose to the tail.

How do you know when wind is tailwind or headwind based off of a figure or like looking at the weather?

The wind moves the wind sock smaller end away, so this smaller end is equivalent to the arrow head on a figure.
Usually the wind is not aligned with the aircraft heading, it is neither a pure tailwind nor a pure headwind. It has both a tail or head wind component and a cross wind component. You need to break the wind vector into its two perpendicular components. On the figure below, if north is up, the aircraft heading is 90° and the wind is about 315°. (The wind sock would have its smaller end aligned with the blue arrow head.)

Now you have isolated the tail/head component, you can evaluate its direction and determine whether this component comes from the tail or from the nose.
Indeed one component can be null, e.g. if the wind is perpendicular to the aircraft heading, there is a cross wind component but no tail/head wind component. Actually that's the angle between the heading and the wind which can tell you quickly if there is a tail or head wind component:

If the wind blows from a direction which forms an angle smaller than 90° with the aircraft heading, then the wind has a head wind component.

If the wind blows from a direction which forms an angle larger than 90° with the aircraft heading, then the wind has a tail wind component.



This 90° angle limit determines four quarters, head-left, head-right, tail-left, tail-right for the direction the wind is blowing from. This notion of quarters is the one used in the picture you included in your question. E.g. if the heading is 270° and the wind is 315°, the angle from nose to wind direction is 45° on the right, this is a right-quartering head wind:

Note your heading and the wind direction are not using the same convention on your second picture. It looks like your wind is 315° and your heading is 90°, or your heading is 270° and your wind is 135°, depending on where north is.
The magnitude of the tail/head wind component is proportional to the wind magnitude and to the cosine of the angle. The cross wind magnitude, which depends on the wind magnitude and the sine, is also important as any aircraft has a cross wind limitation for taking off and landing.

A headwind means the wind is coming toward your head (the nose of the airplane). A tailwind means the wind is coming toward your tail (the tail of the airplane).
Runways are numbered: What would your compass say if you were pointed straight down the runway.
Wind direction is numbered: What would your compass say if you were angled so that the wind was a perfect headwind.
This makes it very easy. If the wind is "270 at 10" and you are on "runway 27" it is a perfect/direct headwind. If (like in your example) the wind is "300 at 10" and you are on "runway 27" it is a right quartering headwind.
If you think about it in terms of geometry/trigonometry, a perfect headwind is pointed straight toward you—0º offset from where your nose is pointed. As the wind shifts, the crosswind component goes up and the headwind component goes down. Eventually the wind is coming directly from your side—in other words, 90º offset from where your nose is pointed. This is a complete crosswind. As the wind continues to shift, the crosswind component goes down and the tailwind component goes up until eventually the wind is coming from right behind you—in other words, 180º offset from where your nose is pointed.

Wind is from, and runways are to a given direction.
Start by adding West, South, and East (you have North) to your diagram.
The red wind arrow is correct.  The windsock confirms wind from the northwest.
The yellow landing arrow is $backwards$, representing a landing on eastbound runway 9.  The pilot would have a left quartering tailwind.
Turn the landing around to a more sensible runway 27, and one has a right quartering headwind, landing to the West.

The opening of the wind sock is where the wind comes from. You are landing on runway 27 so you are heading toward 270 magnetic, from right to left in this diagram. So the wind is coming from the right and from ahead. Try draw everything on a flat sheet of paper to create look from above view.
